# Comparison of two proteomic analysis results on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that a large number of similar questions have already been asked here, but I still don't know how to apply this to my data. How can I create a plot in which I could combine corresponding pairs? In way like this:

[image]

I have the results of an analysis of a set of proteins from two types of cells (tumor and non-tumor) taken from patients. The samples were measured on mass spectrometry. They were saved in csv format. For each patient they look roughly like this:

| Protein | TUMOR | NTUMOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4318100 | 250100 |
| B | 2356000 | 561100 |
| C | 14500 | 0 |
| D | 5468000 | 12500 |

and I have them saved as for example patient610.csv
so I can do this:

```
p610 = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Gliwice\\Bazy_danych\\10.23\\patient610.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

But when I try create plot with ggplot I still have a comunicates about Error.
How can I achieve that using ggplot in R?

I have tried using ggplot.

```
p610 = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Gliwice\\Bazy_danych\\10.23\\patient610.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
x6=p610$TUMOR

ggplot(data = a610, mapping = aes(x=x6, group = x6))
```

or I created another csv file that looks like this one:

| Patient | TUMOR | Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | 4318100 | 1 |
| T | 2356000 | 2 |
| T | 14500 | 3 |
| T | 5468000 | 4 |
| N | 250100 | 1 |
| N | 561100 | 2 |
| N | 0 | 3 |
| N | 12500 | 4 |

and run with:

```
ggplot(p610, aes(y = x6)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 8), size = 5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = rep(c(-1, 1), each = 8), group = Id))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't depend on ggplot you can try

```
reshape(dat, idvar='Id', dir='w', timevar='Patient')[-1] |> rev() |> t() |> 
  matplot(type='o', pch=20, lty=1, ylab='score', xaxt='n', xlim=c(.75, 2.25)) + 
  axis(1, seq_along(unique(dat$Patient)), labels=rev(unique(dat$Patient)))
legend('topleft', pch=20, col=seq_along(unique(dat$Id)), 
       legend=paste('id', unique(dat$Id)), ncol=2, cex=.8)
```

[image]

Or on log scale maybe

```
reshape(transform(dat, TUMOR=TUMOR + 1), idvar='Id', dir='w', timevar='Patient')[-1] |> rev() |> t() |> 
  matplot(type='o', pch=20, lty=1, ylab='score', xaxt='n', xlim=c(.75, 2.25), log='y') + 
  axis(1, seq_along(unique(dat$Patient)), labels=rev(unique(dat$Patient)))
legend('bottomright', pch=20, col=seq_along(unique(dat$Id)), 
       legend=paste('id', unique(dat$Id)), ncol=2, cex=.8)
```

### [image]

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Patient = c("T", "T", "T", "T", "N", "N", "N", 
"N"), TUMOR = c(4318100L, 2356000L, 14500L, 5468000L, 250100L, 
561100L, 0L, 12500L), Id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A ggplot solution would entail pivoting your data (in the first format) to long format and applying a pseudo-log scale.

```r
library(tidyverse)

p610 %>%
  pivot_longer(-Protein) %>%
  mutate(`Cell Type` = ifelse(name == 'TUMOR', 'Tumor', 'Non-tumor')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(`Cell Type`, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Protein)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Protein), size = 4) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log1p', breaks = c(0, 10^(1:7)),
                     labels = scales::comma) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
p610 <- data.frame(Protein = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                   TUMOR   = c(4318100, 2356000, 14500, 5468000), 
                   NTUMOR  = c(250100, 561100, 0, 12500))
```